# strrev() Function and Integers in PHP

Tags: php

I've seen a function that checks if a number is a palindrome.

```
class Solution {
    function isPalindrome($x) {
        return $x >= 0 && $x === (int)strrev($x);
    }
}
```

My question is: while the strrev function should accept a string as an argument, here it takes an integer and works fine. How is this possible?

Comment: PHP automatically converts types when necessary. String functions will convert a number to a string, and numeric functions will convert a string to a number.

Comment: [Type juggling](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php)

Answer (score 0):

PHP follows Perl's convention when dealing with arithmetic operations on character variables and not C's. For example, in PHP and Perl $a = 'Z'; $a++; turns $a into 'AA', while in C a = 'Z'; a++; turns a into '[' (ASCII value of 'Z' is 90, ASCII value of '[' is 91). Note that character variables can be incremented but not decremented and even so only plain ASCII alphabets and digits (a-z, A-Z and 0-9) are supported. Incrementing/decrementing other character variables has no effect, the original string is unchanged.

```php
$s = 'W';
for ($n=0; $n<6; $n++) {
    echo ++$s . PHP_EOL;
}
```

The above example will output:

X

Y

Z

AA

AB

AC